# jQuery attach click event on empty select box

Tags: jquery

using jQuery, how do i load select box options dynamically while clicking on the select box.

I am using redmine REST API's to load issue categories dynamically in to select box.

How do i attach event handler to the selectbox.

But this is not working, i.e event not attaching

```
<script>
    //dynamically load status values
    $('#newstatusField').on('click',function(){     
        alert('inside');
    });
</script>
<select name="status" id="newstatusField" data-mini="true" data-native-menu="false">
 <!--dynamic option values -->
</select>
```

Comment: wrap your click event with in `$(function(){ // code goes here });`

Comment: I tried but it is not triggering

Comment: @user2629419 what error you got in console ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always try to wrap the jQuery code inside document.ready fucntion and [Change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event will work for you :

**Edit :**  Also include latest jQuery library you can download from here [jQuery Library](http://jquery.com/download/)

```
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function()
    {

         $('#newstatusField').on('change',function(){     
            alert('inside');
         });

    });

    </script>

</head>
```